# Unable to select option from auto-complete list using Selenium

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I'm trying to learn `Selenium` and I have chosen Goibibo website for practice, where I'm trying to do flight search using `Selenium` and trying to enter source and destination but I'm unable to do it.

```
reqdBrwser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gosuggest_inputSrc\"]")).sendKeys(source);
reqdBrwser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
reqdBrwser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gosuggest_inputSrc\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
reqdBrwser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gosuggest_inputSrc\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: For Selenium related question, please provide the following information the exception and stack trace you are getting, and all or part of the HTML Selenium is interacting with. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that using key events is correct way of handling the popup dropdown, I would rather recommend going for [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) like

1. Type keys of the origin
2. Wait until first suggestion appears
3. Click the first suggestion

Example code:

```
driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.id("gosuggest_inputSrc")).sendKeys("Mumbai");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("react-autosuggest-1-suggestion--0"))).click();
```

More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)